# Probability density funciton from CDF - one step in derivation

Tags: calculus, probability

In the book I'm reading it says:

From the definition of CDF:
$$P(x_1 \le X<x_2) = F(x_2)-F(x_1)$$

As $\Delta x = x_{2}-x_1 \to 0$, we have

$$P(x_1 \le X<x_2) = dF(x)+r(x)$$

where $r(x)$ is an infinitesimal of higher order than $\Delta x$.

Shouldn't there be just $dF(x)$ on RHS of the equation? I'm not quite sure where $r(x)$ comes from.

Comment: Does the book give you any other properties of $r(x)$, such as $r(x) = 0$ on the support of $dF(x)$, or something similar?

Comment: No. This is all I know about $r(x)$.

Comment: Oh, I see you wrote something about $r(x)$ being an infinitesimal. Think of $r(x)$ as a thing that goes to zero faster than $\Delta x$. It comes from the definition of the derivative as a linear approximation in a local neighborhood. There are several ways to interpret this that are more or less equivalent.

Comment: Where can I read more about it? I thought $dF(x)$ itself was  a good approximation of the difference of function values as points get closer a closer to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way: In the neighborhood of $x_1$, the CDF can be represented by its Taylor series expansion:

$$
F(x_2) = F(x_1) + F'(x_1) (x_2-x_1) + F''(x_1) \frac{(x_2-x_1)^2}{2!} + \cdots
$$

Subtract $F(x_1)$ from both sides to get

$$
P(x_1 \leq X < x_2) = F(x_2)-F(x_1) = F'(x_1) (x_2-x_1)
                    + F''(x_1) \frac{(x_2-x_1)^2}{2!} + \cdots
$$

or, after a slight abuse of notation,

$$
P(x_1 \leq X < x_2) = dF(x_1) + F''(x_1)\frac{(\Delta x)^2}{2!} + \cdots
$$

So $r(x)$ is just all those higher order terms off to the right, all of which are $(\Delta x)^2$ or more.  We often write $o((\Delta x)^2)$ in place of $r(x)$, to indicate that all the omitted terms are no more significant than $(\Delta x)^2$.

Presumably, this step is prelude to dividing by $\Delta x$ and taking the limit as $\Delta x \to 0$ to yield the relationship between the PDF and the CDF:

$$
f(x) = \frac{dF(x)}{dx}
$$